# Malleability of El Gamal encryption

Tags: elgamal-signature, malleability

Suppose Alice encrypts a number  which indicates her bid on a contract, using textbook **ElGamal** encryption (malleable). This encryption of  produces a ciphertext pair **1** and **2**.

How can Eve modify **1** and **2** to make it a modified value of **2** which is an arbitrary value of ? (eg. 1% more than x)

For a modified message **two times of** , I know that the modified ciphertext pair would be **(1, 2 * 2)**. As seen [here in this lecture](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Egasarch/COURSES/456/F18/lec25/lec25.pdf).

But what about arbitrary values?

Comment: So you have an example of how to modify the ciphertext to double the plaintext. Do you know *why* that works?

Comment: What made you think your approach will not work? If you apply the decryption operation to your ciphertext $(c_1, 10 \cdot c_2)$, what plaintext will you get?

Comment: You forgot the reduction modulo the prime. $10 * 6 = 60 \equiv 2 \pmod{29}$. As ElGamal operates over a finite group $\mathbb{Z}_p$, one has to take care to stay within the confines of this group.

Comment: Exactly. In this case there's only 28 possible plaintexts and ciphertexts, which we would commonly associate with the numbers $\{1, 2, \ldots, 28\}$

Comment: Regarding your edit: Mind that messages and ciphertexts must be group members. So it makes little sense to talk about "arbitrary values" such as "1% more than $x$", as this is not well-defined in this context. Mathematically it makes little sense as it conflates the multiplicative group operation with the multiplication over the reals, but also intuitively it is clear that e.g $1.01 \cdot 6 = 6.01$ is not a member of $\{1, 2, \ldots, 28\}$.

Comment: With straight ElGamal in $\mathbb Z_p^*$, knowing the public key and parameters, and a ciphertext for $x$, and under the assumption $x$ is a multiple of $100$ and sizably less than the public modulus, there is a simple method to build a ciphertext which when deciphered yields $x'$ equal to 1% more than $x$. Hint: express the ratio $x'/x$.

Answer (score 0):

If you have $c=E(r_1, m)$ you can multiply it with $E(r_2, 1)$ and then you have :
$$c' = E(r_1, m)E(r_2, 1)=(g^{r_1}, my^{r_1})(g^{r_2}, y^{r_2}) = (g^{r_1+r_2},my^{r_1+r_2}) = E(r_1+r_2,m)$$
So you just got an ecryption $c'$ of the very same message $m$ but with different secret key $r_1+r_2$ without even knowing the initial secret key $r_1$